# Gradle fails to build ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I'm using new Android studio, based on IDEA, and trying to build project with ABS library in dependencies for the main module.
And I'm getting errors:

```
Gradle: package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol class SherlockActivity
Gradle: package com.actionbarsherlock.view does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol variable super
Gradle: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
....
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169635/disable-swiping-between-tabs-in-fragmentactivity

Comment: I don't know what relation it has to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used build ok.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}
```

Comment: @Cossle Song Can you explain how I can implement this?

Comment: @ParthMehrotra you need create build.gradle use up info, and your main project reference it, e.g.(compile project(':ActionBar'))

Answer (score 1):

I was putting this as a comment because I wasn't sure if its your exact issue but it looks like `abs` isn't added as a `module` correctly. So I added as an answer

Try download `abs` fresh, extract it then in `Android Studio` - `file > import module...` and import the actionbarsherlock directory. After this however I had a error relating to junit so check the last steps in below post

Follow the steps here: [Problems importing project into Android Studio regarding ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577580/problems-importing-project-into-android-studio-regarding-actionbarsherlock)

That post isn't your exact issue but the steps got `abs` working for me. so try that within your existing project

Answer (score 1):

I did the import module, but i still had to add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency and then that got it working.

(actually i had the toplevel exception for mismatched support libs too, but then i got it working)