# Android - Remove Title Bar (ActionBar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Can anyone tell me how to do the following,

1. Remove The App Title bar & keep the action bar.
2. Move Tab Bar(Action Bar) to the bottom of the screen.
3. Remove Swipe Feature from the Tab.

[image]

Comment: 3 questions for the price of one!

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
   Myactionbar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); Myactionbar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Where my action bar is the name of your action bar

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Just put this two line in ocreate will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

in your manifest file for your activity

Comment: f i use this feature app crashes because its expecting to find Actionbar to add tabs

Answer (score 1):

We have to clarify some contents of your question:

1. the "app title bar" is part of the `Action Bar`, so they are the same thing; in other words you can't "divide" them, at last you can delete the title of your application;
2. you can't move the Action Bar to the bottom of the screen, but you can **split** it, as it says this [official link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) (see *Using split action bar* paragraph); this can be do only if `Action Bar` is activated;
3. if you want to remove swipe feature from tab, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169635/disable-swiping-between-tabs-in-fragmentactivity).

As you can see on [this link](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/tabs-top-or-bottom.html) and in [this one](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/tips-for-android-tabs.html), **tabs on bottom are discouraged by Google** (i don't wanna launch a discussion about this, forgive me).

But of course, you are free to do whatever you want with your app, and i found very usefull [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395661/android-tabs-at-the-bottom).

That's all i can do. If you get struck again, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.NO_ACTION_BAR)
```

would do the trick ! Do it before setting the content view.

Comment: If i use this feature app crashes because its expecting to find Actionbar to add tabs

Answer (score 0):

To remove the very top bar Inside your oncreate() method place this

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Now for the action bar to move it to the bottom there is no preset it can only be placed on the top unless you make your own interface visit this link

http://android-ed.blogspot.ca/2011/12/using-actionbar-at-bottom-of-screen.html

Hope that helps !

Comment: If i use this feature app crashes because its expecting to find Actionbar to add tabs