# Android remove title bar from Action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I have an activity in my app, which is using swipeable tabs with action bar

For example :-

[this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

So my question is to add action bar to my activity and remove titlbar

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267361/android-remove-title-bar-actionbar)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269798/1761003

Comment: both are same.. title bar and actionbar

Comment: tell me what you want to do exactly

Comment: I want to remove title bar and add action bar to the activity

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your activity before calling setContentView();

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR | Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

if that dosen't work try this

```
//use this to disable the icon from ActionBar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    //use this to disable the application name from ActionBar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to exactly *what you class as a title bar* but you could do this in XML by putting the following in your Android Manifest for a particular activity to remove your title bar.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

Comment: i don't think this would work as setting a theme in the manifest file won't affect a fragment

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in oncreate() method of activity before adding content:

```
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```