# How to disable the "swipe between tabs" in the Tabbed Activity template created by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-studio

When I create this activity:

[image]

it comes with that swipe feature enabled, just like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169635/disable-swiping-between-tabs-in-fragmentactivity).

The problem with that same post is that the solution found uses *TabHost* which is deprecated and it is not what this Tabbed Activity template uses. Moreover, I want to believe that this feature can be disabled without having to land a craft on Mars and prove the existence of God.

How can I do this in the most simple way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extend `ViewPager` and override few methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328606/759007 . In addition you should also replace `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with `your.package.name.CustomViewPager` inside layout xml file.