# Disable swiping between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I set up sliding tabs with two `Fragment`s each `Fragment` has a `Button` which goes to a `WebView`. The problem with this is when the `WebView` `Button` is clicked the sliding tabs are still activated and when a user tries to navigate within the `WebView` you end up swiping to the other tab. Is there a way in an on click method to disable the swiping ability of the tabs? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Here the code:

```
public class MyWebViewClass extends Fragment {

private WebView mWebView;
private Button mButton;

public MyWebViewClass() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);

    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.WebView);

    mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure that there is such functionality in whatever libs you are using, but question is how or rather when to enable it again ...

Comment: @Selvin yes i Thought that myself, I'm using MaterialTabs by neokree, but I couldn't find any way to disable the sliding tabs. Here's the Link https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Comment: ok instead using MaterialTab  make your own class which extends this class and override onTouch(...) like this `bool onTouch(params) {if(someFlagThatMeansThatSlidingIsDissable) { return false; } return super.onTouch(params)}`  add some getter and setter for this flag ... then use setter to dissable/enable sliding .... sounds pretty easy (but of course i will not write the code for you - well because it is almost aready written in this comment) ... edit: as i wrote before, problem is when to enable it again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169635/disable-swiping-between-tabs-in-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**This answer can be applied to any ViewPager actually no matter what is the library you are using to implement the tabs or even a normal ViewPager without tabs.**

The library you are using [neokree/MaterialTabs](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs) is backed with a ViewPager that is responsible for the swiping effect and you can disable that by using the new [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) or providing your own custom ViewPager.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class CustomViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {

    var isPagingEnabled: Boolean = true

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

This class provides a ViewPager that is swiping enabled and you can turn it off by `viewPager.isPagingEnabled = false`

No to mention that you have to change the XML layout to your new custom ViewPager rather than the original one.

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager 
   ...
   />
```

to

```
<my.package.CustomViewPager 
   ...
   />
```

Comment: Great answer thanks very much just one problem im not really sure how to set up the adapter in the Main Activity? I have `ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` what should i change this to?

Comment: You shouldn't change that.

Comment: is there anything i should change?

Comment: you have to change the xml layout to your new custom ViewPager rather than the original one. and then get the variable like always but in a CustomViewPager object not just a ViewPager  obj then call the `mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);` whenever you need.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply great answer, took me a while to get my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: great but tab click also should be disable

Answer (score 27):

Kotlin:

Using ViewPager2...

```
viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

Swiping between tab is disabled and the user can still tap tabs at the top to go between tabs.

[Documentation on isUserInputEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#isUserInputEnabled())

Comment: The most actual and clear solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to `setOnTouchListener` and return `true` for `ViewPager`.

original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392198/4293813

Answer (score 1):

## Accepted Answer's AndroidX and Kotlin Version:

### ViewPager with paging disabled all the time

```
package your.packg.name //CustomViewPager's location actually

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class CustomViewPager(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet?
) :
    ViewPager(context!!, attrs) {
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

---

### ViewPager with paging switchable to on or off at anytime.

```
package your.packg.name //CustomViewPager's location actually

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class CustomViewPager(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet?
) :
    ViewPager(context!!, attrs) {
    var isPagingEnabled = false   //Modify this in code for switch

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

---

Lastly, find ViewPager line in **XML** file and modify according to your CustomViewPager location, i.e.:

#### `<your.packg.name.CustomViewPager ...`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code.

```
viewpager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.