# Android TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I am using this Android [library](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout).
I don't want to swipe to change view but to tap. I mean both works but can I disable swiping somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class, just turn it off like this:

```
mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

[Accourding to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28504193/4409113)