# Make tabs in SlidingTabLayout not slide

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I recently made an app using `SlidingTabLayout` with two tabs. I referred this [link](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html.)

[image: Sliding Tabs]

However I had to modify it slightly. I had to add a button which **locks the sliding of the tabs**. And unlock it when it is clicked again. So I just can't get the tabs to not slide.

I checked out this question [Disable swiping between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503599/disable-swiping-between-tabs). But he is using some other library to do it and it's no longer supported. I'm using the default one. And in that question the CustomViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. In my project ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Any help would be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you just post your code.

Comment: Post your modified code

Comment: It's the same. I haven't modified it. If i got to know the logic of not sliding the tabs I can proceed further. Thank you

Comment: So you want lock changing tabs. If I click on button I can't change tab, but then I click again, the feature is unlocked, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable swiping between tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503599/disable-swiping-between-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a custom ViewPager which extends the ViewPager and set a method that disables and enables the swiping.

You can do that by adding a class like the one below to your code. Then instead of using ViewPager just use CustomViewPager in your code:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
             return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

You can disable/enable swiping by calling: `setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled).`

Comment: Have you checked out the ViewPager of the link I specified? Are you telling me to replace that fully?

Comment: The ViewPager is from the android support v4 library, and yes, I checked and saw that it was used in your code. So basically I am saying, add this class to your code and replace ViewPager with CustomViewPager where it  is used. There actually are not so many references where you need to replace it

Comment: And how do I call this in MainActivity as the current one is using FragmentManager

Comment: you never call it using the FragmentManager in the code you provided, you call the adapter that way. As for the custom ViewPager you just use it like this `CustomViewPager pager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);`

Comment: It's giving an error: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to mvk.com.slidingtabs.CustomViewPager. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well your CustomViewPager should extend the ViewPager from mvk.com.slidingtabs not the one from the support library. Sorry, my bad, I thought you used that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98678/discussion-between-mvk059-and-irina-avram).