# Disable sliding in one sliding tab

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm making an app that will have three tabs, one of them should have a map fragment.

I created tabs using TabActivity, which is now deprecated. It is recommended to use sliding tabs. My question would be this - can I disable one tab (the one with the map fragment), or is it already disabled for map? Also should I use this code (with TabActivity) or use sliders?

My original code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // First tab
    Intent intentTabOne = new Intent().setClass(this, TabOneActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecTabOne = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Tab One")
        .setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_one_config))
        .setContent(intentTabOne);

    // Second tab
    Intent intentTabTwo = new Intent().setClass(this, TabTwoActivity.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecSecondTab = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Tab Two")
        .setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_two_config))
        .setContent(intentTabTwo);

    // Third tab
    Intent intentTabThree = new Intent().setClass(this, TabThree.class);
    TabSpec tabSpecSent = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("Tab Three")
        .setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_three_invitations_config))
        .setContent(intentTabThree);

    // add all tabs
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTabOne);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTabTwo);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecTabThree);

        //set Windows tab as default 
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into ViewPager since TabActivity has now been deprecated.

Another [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503599/disable-swiping-between-tabs) using ViewPager suggests that you can disable swiping/sliding on it using a custom ViewPager. You can check out the issue linked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already did use ViewPager and replaced it with a custom ViewPager in the app_bar_main, and it worked, but I forgot to answer this question  :)